# Qual o melhor metodo de realizar um menu com submenus ( while com breaks ou chamando os menus em funcoes )?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Para um trabalho escolar preciso ter um menu com vários submenus. Qual é a melhor maneira de abordar isso? 
Posso colocar os menus dentro de *whiles* e ir dando `break` a esses *whiles* quando quiser voltar para o anterior ou separar os menus em funções e ir chamando quando preciso.

Não sei qual seria a melhor opção, estou aberto a sugestões, desde já obrigado.
por exemplo

while 1:

```
# menu principal
existe()
print("========================")
print("     SA Airlines    ")
print("========================")
print("[1] - Adicionar")
print("[2] - Listar")
print("[3] - Procurar")
print(" ")
res = int(input("Opcao: "))

if res == 1:
    add.adicionar()
elif res == 2:

    while 1:

        # um menu secundario
        print("[1] - Aeronaves")
        print("[2] - Aeroportos")
        print("[3] - Rotas")
        print("[4] - Voltar")

        res = int(input("Opcao: "))
        if res == 1:
            listar.mostraAeronaves()
        elif res == 2:
            listar.mostraAeroportos()
        elif res == 3:
            listar.mostraRotas()
        elif res == 4:
            break;
        else:
            print("ERRO: A opção não se encontra defenida ! tente novamente!")
```

Comment: É melhor colocares também o que tens e/ou um exemplo do resultado final que queres. Podes editar aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/172820/edit

Comment: já postei o código que tenho, penso que daqui já da para ter uma ideia do que estáva a tentar fazer

Comment: Olá SKL13D, uma opção é ter dicionários representando cada *nível* do menu. O valor de cada chave é ou uma função (a qual você pode [chamar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9168387/664577)) ou outro dicionário (representando um outro nível de menus).

Comment: Precisas do while ali? Porquê?

Comment: era para voltar a apresentar novamente o menu até o utilizador querer voltar para o anterior ou sair do programa mesmo, mas acho que com a dica que o Anthony deu consigo colocar o menu direito, vou ver.

Comment: Use funções.
Imagine que a função não precisa saber de onde foi chamada  - eala panneas exibe suas opções e devolve a resposta. 
E ai você percebe qu enão precisa ter diferença das funções que exibem sub-menus e as que efetivamente fazem coisas do sistema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando inventaram funções para programar, é por que elas são 
MUITO melhores para organizar o códigoe  a estrtura do programa - 
e isso inclui organizar a estrutura de menus: você não deve pensar
que só as funcionalidades nas pontas deveriam ser funções e que
qualqer código no corpo principal, de qualquer jeito, serve para
fazer os menus.

Se os menus todos se comportam da mesma forma: tem que exibir uma lista de opções, pegar um número
e executar alguma outra coisa baseada nesse número, a melhor coisa que você faz é criar uma
função genérica para exibir esses menus epegar a resposta - e aí você fica com toda a pre de estrutura
do programa bem curtinha e separada da lógica principal:

```
aeronaves = []
aeroportos = []


def menu(titulo, opcoes):
    while True:
        print("=" * len(titulo), titulo, "=" * len(titulo), sep="\n")
        for i, (opcao, funcao) in enumerate(opcoes, 1):
            print("[{}] - {}".format(i, opcao))
        print("[{}] - Retornar/Sair".format(i+1))
        op = input("Opção: ")
        if op.isdigit():
            if int(op) == i + 1:
                # Encerra este menu e retorna a função anterior
                break
            if int(op) < len(opcoes):
                # Chama a função do menu:
                opcoes[int(op) - 1][1]()
                continue
        print("Opção inválida. \n\n")

def principal():
    opcoes = [
        ("Adicionar", adicionar),
        ("Listar", listar),
        ("Procurar", procurar)
    ]
    return menu("SA AIRLINES", opcoes)

def adicionar():
    opcoes = [
        ("Aeronaves", adicionar_aeronave),
        ("Aeroportos", adicionar_aeroporto),
        # ...
    ]
    return menu("Adicionar", opcoes)

def adicionar_aeronave():
    aeronaves.append(input("Nova aeronave: "))


def adicionar_aeroporto():
    aeroportos.append(input("Nova aeronave: "))

    #...

def listar():
   ...

def procurar():
   ...

principal()
```

Eu usei uma característica importante do Python que é a possibilidade de passar funções como objetos normais - ou seja, a função "menu"  recebe as próprias funções que deve chamr, em cada opção, com parâmetros - e chama as funções apropriadas na linha `opcoes[int(op) - 1][1]()`.

As funções que usam o menu definem  as opções como uma sequência de items com dois outros items internos: o primeiro é o nome imprimível da opção, e o segundo é a própria função, como um objeto. Para isso é só colocar o nome da função sem acrescentar os `( )` que caracterizam a chamada da função. (Senão o Python simplesmente chama a função incondicionalmente, naquele ponto, e adiciona o valor retornado pela mesma na lista de opções)

Assim, a linha `opcoes[int(op) - 1][1]()` "diz" dentro item "op - 1" das opções , pegue o segundo item  - que é a própria função (isso declaramos dentro das várias funções que declaram opções para chamar o  `menu`) e chame esse objeto como uma função, sem parâmetros.

Perceba que fazendo desse jeito, se amanã você resolve adiconar uma interface gráfica por exemplo em vez de usar prints e inputs, basta refazer a função "menu" e toda a a estrutra do programa continua funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Repare que o código que postou, fez com que eu aprende-se muitas coisas que não sabia, e que são mesmo uteis ! e estou agradecido a sua disponibilidade para me ensinar isto ( principalmente aquela técnica de chamar as funções, que me vai ajudar muito, já que sou "novato a python"). devo também salientar que nesta parte do codigo **if int(op) == i:** deveria ser **if int(op) == i+1:** porque o **i** só iria de **1 a X** (sendo X o tamanho da lista), sendo que a opção de retornar/sair estaria um valor á frente de i como fez no **format(i+1)**,

Comment: Dito isto, obrigado !

Comment: Legal você ter achado o meu erro. Pra mim éimportante por que signific que você entendeu a idéia. (vou arrumar já).

Comment: Estive de volta de volta desta mas não tive tempo de terminar. Está bom +1, uma pergunta, não poderias chamar `funcao()` já que estás a fazer unpacking no ciclo for? Em vez de `opcoes[int(op) - 1][1]()`?

Comment: O objeto função é acessado em `opcoes[int(op) - 1][1]` - e uma vez que você tem refereência a ele, pode chama-lo, simplesmente colocano os parenteses.

Nada impede que você faça uma referencia a esse mesmo objeto em uma outra variável uma ou algumas linhas acima - (e essa variável pode ser chamada  "funcao") -e nesse caso `funcao()` faria exatamente a mesma chamada, sim.

No codigo acima, no entanto, a variável "funcao" aponta para cada opção do menu só dentro do loop `for` -  fora dele, onde a opção do usuário é usada, `funcao` sempre aponta para a ultima função da lista de opções.

Comment: Ha claro que sim, distração minha, não reparei que já tinhas saido do for quando a usas. Desculpa jsbueno